# ng-options will not pre-select an option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I am using angular's ng-options to populate the html with the names of people. I want it to pre-select the value that I have set as the ng-model (registrantSelected). But for some reason, it won't do so.

I have looked up various different documentations for ng-options and looked at a bunch of other stack overflow posts about ng-options, but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Code can be found in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NH2MGaSmKDuegzQCTW8O?p=preview) or below:

**Javascript:**

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller("MainController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.paidDuesCompanyPeople = [{
            "FirstName": "Person",
            "LastName": "One",
            "MemberType": {
                "IsMember": false,
                "Name": "Non-member"
            }
        }, {
           "FirstName": "Second",
           "LastName": "Person",
           "MemberType": {
               "IsMember": true,
               "Name": "Member"
           }
        }, {
           "FirstName": "Three",
           "LastName": "People",
           "MemberType": {
               "IsMember": false,
               "Name": "Non-member"
        }
    }];

        $scope.registrantSelected = {
            "FirstName": "Person",
            "LastName": "One",
            "MemberType": {
                "IsMember": false,
                "Name": "Non-member"
            }
        };
    }]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Registration for</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <select class="form-control" ng-model="registrantSelected" ng-options="person.FirstName + ' ' + person.LastName for person in paidDuesCompanyPeople">
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  {{registrantSelected}}
</div>
```

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: $scope.registrantSelected isn't the same object... you need to set using paidDuesCompanyPeople[0], or using track by on ng-options to define a field to compare on selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this thing by introducing `track by` in your `ng-options` but for having `track by` you should have unique property over there. I'd highly recommnd you to add `Id` property so that would make each record unique & you can track by the same. But for now just for demonstration you can track it by `person.FirstName + person.Lastname`(you will have track by person.Id when you add id)

```
<select class="form-control" 
   ng-model="registrantSelected" 
   ng-options="person.FirstName + ' ' + person.LastName for person in paidDuesCompanyPeople track by person.FirstName + person.Lastname ">
</select>
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rAiDK2F1T6gWmoV5HJK6?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! Using track by and adding a unique id fixed my issue perfectly.

Comment: @eclaire211 Glad to help you, Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set it in the controller, like so...

```
$scope.registrantSelected = $scope.paidDuesCompanyPeople[0];
```

Which makes your controller look like this (drop it in your plunkr)

**Edit:** I have added a plunkr as requested  http://plnkr.co/edit/r8XAWqBheAATwc8zXGSY?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller("MainController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.paidDuesCompanyPeople = [{
      "FirstName": "Person",
      "LastName": "One",
      "MemberType": {
        "IsMember": false,
        "Name": "Non-member"
      }
    },{
      "FirstName": "Second",
      "LastName": "Person",
      "MemberType": {
        "IsMember": true,
        "Name": "Member"
      }
    },{
      "FirstName": "Three",
      "LastName": "People",
      "MemberType": {
        "IsMember": false,
        "Name": "Non-member"
      }
    }];

    $scope.registrantSelected = $scope.paidDuesCompanyPeople[0];
  }]);
```

if you want to do it in the view,

```
<select ng-model="registrantSelected" 
        ng-options="person.FirstName + ' ' + person.LastName for person in paidDuesCompanyPeople" 
        ng-init="registrantSelected=paidDuesCompanyPeople[0]"></select>
```

Comment: can you share a plunk? I was facing a similar issue once.

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje sure. does this work for you? http://plnkr.co/edit/r8XAWqBheAATwc8zXGSY?p=preview

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje you can refer to mine answer as well, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

change registrantSelected value to this:

```
$scope.registrantSelected = $scope.paidDuesCompanyPeople[0];
```

in javascript every two objects are the same only if both of them are referring to same object:

```js
var x1 = { id : 1 };
var x2 = { id : 1 }; 
console.log(x1 == x2); // false

var y1 = { id : 1 };
var y2 = y1;
console.log(y1 == y2); // true
```